# How to add an attribute to an instance of a Java class through Jython at runtime

Tags: java, jython, monkeypatching

I am using Jython 2.5 (but could change to 2.7 if necessary).
Among other things, my jython code manipulates instances of a java class of an imported jar library.

Say the java library code is

```
public class A extends B implements C
{
  public A(int a)
  {
     this.var1 = a;
  }
  public getVar1()
  {
     return this.var1;
  }
  public setVar1(a)
  {
     this.var1 = a;
  }
}
```

Within my Jython script, I have access to instances (objects) of the A class and can do

```
var1 = myinstance.getVar1()
```

in order to get attribute `var1`.

My issue is the following: I want to add another attribute to all instances of ClassA at runtime, a 'var2' field.

This should exist on all instances of ClassA but have a different actual value for every instance of the class (be bound to the object, not the class).

If this succeeds, I also want to dynamically add a `getVar2()` method to these objects that gets whatever is stored in `self.var2` for every object.

The problem is: As far as I understand, if ClassA was python, this would have been possible. But because it is a java class, jython doesn't allow this [ even when setting `python.security.respectJavaAccessibility = false` ]

One idea I found out in a jython book is the following:

> Adding attributes: You cannot add attributes to a Java instance at
>   runtime with an assignment statement. To gain this ability, you can
>   create a Jython subclass of the Java object. You will then be able to
>   add attributes to the instance of the subclass.

So it should be possible to wrap the java class and *existing* objects using a python class which has the additional attribute and use these new objects later on in my code.

However I am not sure how that can be done or if there are alternatives.

Thoughts?